# Snap stopped working on wsl?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have WSL2 preview version installed (so I can use the new systemd support). I'm running the latest version of WSL Ubuntu (not preview) and when I run `snap install <insert_program_here>` or any program installed with snap (like lxd) it returns

```
Interacting with snapd is not yet supported on Windows Subsystem for Linux.
This command has been left available for documentation purposes only.
```

So the `lxd` command has the same output. I also enabled systemd by adding

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```

to `/etc/wsl.conf`

`wsl -v` returns:

```
WSL version: 0.70.4.0
Kernel version: 5.15.68.1
WSLg version: 1.0.45
MSRDC version: 1.2.3575
Direct3D version: 1.606.4
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22000.1098
```

and `snap --version` returns:

```
snap                         2.57.4+22.04
snapd                        unavailable
series                       16
Windows Subsystem for Linux  -
kernel                       5.15.68.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 (amd64)
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu did you use? From your question" you can't interact with snapd or something (on WSL)" We can not guess what the error was.

Comment: Remember, details, details, details !  Show the commands you are using and error messages you receive (formatted in code blocks).  Most people (I'm an exception, clearly) reading this question probably don't remember your previous questions (nor should they), so make sure to add all relevant information *here*.  Last I saw, you were on 0.70.0 of WSL (so if you updated, you are probably on 0.70.4 now) with (probably, based on the Store install) Ubuntu 20.04?  Add that information to the question - A tag based on the Ubuntu version can be helpful to others as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Also confirm that you edited `/etc/wsl.conf` to enable Systemd support as you had previously done before reinstalling.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes sorry for not giving the info I had another problem where I couldnt use WSL at all, but that is fixed now. I am not currently home, but I’ll make sure to update my question when I get home

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I added the details. Sorry it took so long, but as I mentioned above, I wasn't home.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, and @olem for your response. With all the polluted internet with these search terms, this is the only decent answer out there for what's going on with snap right now.

Comment: @rfay Agree that it is a good question.  I've also added a workaround if you haven't seen it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a pull request regarding this problem [here](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/pull/12179).

or

take a look at this forum post [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/running-snaps-on-wsl2-insiders-only-for-now/13033/59).

Comment: Thanks for the info @olem - It was difficult to tell from those links when this problem might start to be fixed. The very confusing thing is that it was all working on several systems... then not working on a couple, then not working on most. Must have to do with windows updates or something?

Comment: @rfay Actually seems to just be Ubuntu 22.04 updates, but let me know if you are seeing something different, and I'll try to test.  See my answer for versions.

Comment: @olem it would be really helpful if you could add some more details from the links in your answer. Currently there is not much information there other than the two links, which would be of no value if for some reason they would stop working. Also have a look at this post from the Help Center for how to write good answers: [How do I write a good answer?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

@EduGomezEscandell [beat me to it](https://askubuntu.com/a/1437511/1165986), but also updating this answer to note that this is fixed in the latest Snapd:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

(or target Snapd specifically as Edu mentions).  After updating, Snap/Snapd should work properly under the latest WSL/Systemd releases.

Remember to revert any workarounds (e.g. below).  A `wsl --shutdown` is also need to return your `binfmt_misc` to normal.

---

Historical information:

As [@olem's answer mentions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1436665/1165986), this does seem to be due to an intentional Snap change that was designed to "fail gracefully" on WSL.  For me, this only appears to be an issue on Ubuntu 22.04 with Snap/Snapd version 2.57.

The version that comes with Ubuntu 22.04 on first install in WSL is currently 2.55, so `snap` works at first, out-of-the-box, then fails after the first `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.

The problem does not appear to occur on Ubuntu 20.04, even when fully updated, as the latest release there is 2.55.5.

According to the [Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1991826), this surfaced when a *separate* bug was recently fixed.

Side-note:  Also being tracked in [this WSL issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9026), although we know it's not actually a problem in WSL itself.

###### Steps you can take if you are experiencing this issue:

- *Implement a temporary workaround*

  A good workaround is found in [this Github comment](https://github.com/ubuntu/WSL/issues/299#issuecomment-1288203645):

  ```
  echo ":windowsexe:M::\x4d\x5a::/init:PF" | sudo tee -a /etc/binfmt.d/windowsexe.conf
  ```

  Then exit Ubuntu, `wsl --terminate <distroname>` (in PowerShell or CMD), and restart.

  This file is processed at startup and "reregisters" the WSL Interop support (that allows you to run Windows binaries) with a different name, thus thwarting the method that Snap uses to detect that it is running under WSL.

---

- *"Upvote" the issue on Launchpad*

  Create an account on the Ubuntu Launchpad and click the [Affects me too](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1991826/+affectsmetoo) link at the top of the issue page.

---

- *Monitor the status*

  You can monitor the status at [the main Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1991826).

  While the fix is merged, it still needs to get pushed into the 22.04 update channel.  From watching [this WSL bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gzip/+bug/1966849) on Launchpad, the fix will first need to go into `jammy-proposed`, where at least one user will need to test and confirm the fix before it will be released to `-updates`.

  I'm honestly not sure how we get this to the next step, though.  I'll attempt to research.

---

- **Important**:  *Revert the temporary workaround once the updated Snapd with the fix is updated on your system*

  Make sure that, when the fix for this bug is pushed into the Ubuntu update channel, that you remove `/etc/binfmt.d/windowsexe.conf` so that you return to allowing WSL to set this up for you.  The method has changed slightly over time, and you'll want to be sure that, in the long-term, you are using the settings that WSL expects.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with snapd 2.57.4. A fix was released today. Simply do

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade snapd
```

This'll upgrade you to snapd 2.57.5 and you'll be set.
As mentioned in another comment, you can see the discussion [in this Github issue](https://github.com/ubuntu/WSL/issues/299)

Comment: Thanks It worked